# Calculating the possible permutations of a data grid rows and columns

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations

Lets say I have to calculate permutations of data in a grid and have limited information about the data I am trying to find. For instance, for each individual row and column (of, say, 10)

- the total value for the set is `x`
- `a` values between 0 and 3
- `b` values between 4 and 7
- `c` values between 8 and 11
- `d` values between 12 and 15

thus each row might be as such

```
x = 76
a = 3
b = 2
c = 1
d = 4
```

from this, we could calculate possible numbers to be in the row / column:

```
 1,  1,  3,  4,  5,  8, 12, 13, 14, 15
15,  3,  3, 12,  4,  8, 12,  4, 14,  1
```

etc

What is the best way to calculate all possible permutations of data in the grid, and do I even have enough information to calculate the data?

**EDIT**

For the following data grid:

```
|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|
|02|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|15|
|03|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|12|10|
|04|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|12|
|05|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|13|10|
|06|02|03|14|05|06|07|08|14|15|
|07|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|15|
|08|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|12|15|
|09|02|03|14|05|06|07|08|09|15|
|10|02|13|04|05|06|07|08|06|15|
```

row data would be

```
01| x = 53, a = 3, b = 4, c = 3, d = 0
02| x = 61, a = 3, b = 4, c = 2, d = 1
03| x = 60, a = 3, b = 4, c = 3, d = 0
04| x = 60, a = 2, b = 5, c = 2, d = 1
05| x = 63, a = 2, b = 5, c = 2, d = 1
06| x = 80, a = 2, b = 4, c = 1, d = 3
07| x = 66, a = 2, b = 5, c = 2, d = 1
08| x = 62, a = 2, b = 4, c = 2, d = 2
09| x = 78, a = 2, b = 3, c = 3, d = 2
10| x = 76, a = 1, b = 5, c = 2, d = 2
```

column data would be

```
01| x = 55,  a =  3, b =  4, c =  3, d = 0
02| x = 20,  a = 10, b =  0, c =  0, d = 0
03| x = 40,  a =  9, b =  0, c =  0, d = 1
04| x = 60,  a =  0, b =  8, c =  0, d = 2
05| x = 50,  a =  0, b = 10, c =  0, d = 0
06| x = 60,  a =  0, b = 10, c =  0, d = 0
07| x = 70,  a =  0, b = 10, c =  0, d = 0
08| x = 80,  a =  0, b =  0, c = 10, d = 0
09| x = 62,  a =  0, b =  1, c =  5, d = 4
10| x = 132, a =  0, b =  0, c =  3, d = 7
```

Comment: You described how data in columns a,b,c and d are generated but how about the the other columns in your example? Also, how many rows are there? You plan to use a computer, correct?

Comment: that data could generate the whole row or column, so, for instance, there would be `a` values between 0 and 3 in a row. There would be 10 rows and 10 columns and each row / column intersection would have a value  between 0 and 15 in them. The data I have is simply the sum of each row and column and also how many of each set of numbers appear per column. See my edit.